# What are the criteria which I should know to distinguish between the business processes that should be a part of my system or using BPM

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, software-design, business-process-management

I want to know what are the signs or the criteria which I should know to distinguish between the business processes that should be a part of my system and the others which could be implemented through `BPM`.

I read [the following](https://speakerdeck.com/francoisroyer/enterprise-ddd-designing-business-processes-and-customer-journeys?slide=42) and I still a little confused:

[image]

---

EX: a `vacation Request` This process consists of set of states for example the employee requests a vacation from his manager and after that, the request goes to the HR management. This process is a part of `HR` system.

> Should I implement it twice or as a BPM or only as an internal process
> in my system?

---

My question is:

What's the best practice for the scenario in which you have a business process? Should we implement it as a standalone process using something like BPM or implementing it as a part of the whole system(and in that case can I get some tips)?

> NOTE: I'm not asking about cost here I'm asking mainly about software
> design perspective?

Comment: Look at temporal.io open source project that allows implementing the business process directly in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One heuristic you could use is to check if the process is universal to all users of the domain.

Let us assume that you are building an HR management system as per your example. Your core domain would involve aspects like hiring, onboarding, payroll, TDS, hierarchies, etc. These functionalities would be applicable across companies/users of your product.

But each company may define a specific approval process differently. Taking your example of vacation approval, one company may want the manager to approve; the other may want the Manager + HR to approve. Another may want to request to be routed to the payroll department to ensure that the no. of available PTO days has not been breached. These are aspects that are best kept out of the domain and modeled in BPM.

Having said that, as the author expands in the slide deck you pointed to, processes in BPM have a nasty habit of intruding into your domain. The best mechanism is to implement user-specific workflows in BPM and refactor once in a while to pull the mechanism into the domain if needed.

Comment: Could U explain the following sentence more plz: `The best mechanism is to implement user-specific workflows in BPM and refactor once in a while to pull the mechanism into the domain if needed`?

Comment: In the example I outlined, different customers may have adopted different authorization workflows within their organizations. Instead of addressing these workflows within your codebase, you could configure them in BPM and only accommodate the endpoints within your application. So BPM contains the workflow of how many depts/people approve and in what order, and your application only captures the approval event. In the future, if you see a repeating workflow pattern across multiple customers, you want to refactor and pull it into your domain logic.

Answer (score 2):

> BPM should be the default for non-Core business activities.

This statement assumes your organisation has specialist systems that deal with "core" business activities (i.e. do stuff to do with the enterprises 'core business'), plus a BPM solution.

For example, in the previous slide they have "In-bound Logistics" as a "primary (aka Core) activity", which suggests that logistics is a core part of their business and that they probably have a specialist system for that such as an ERP, supply chain management software, or maybe even a bespoke system.

Based on that assumption, they are asserting that any non-core activity should (by default) be implemented using a BPM solution - because it's not a good fit with any of the specialist systems.  E.g. you shouldn't try and do support activities such as human resource management in the core logistics system.

The further assertion, which is kind of obvious logically following from that, is that BPM should also be the default ahead of building a bespoke app or any other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, a simple checklist could look like:

1. Do you make **money** off of the activity? If yes, it's probably core.
2. How many **specialized functions** do you require of the process? If it's > 5 then it's probably core to your business and generic solutions will increase the difficulty to implement, maintain, and upgrade.
3. If you build it, could you **sell** it to a competitor? If not, it's probably not core.

There are probably more. If I think of them I'll add them.